# I had to recover InnoDB tables from my backup, but mysql is crashing

Tags: mysql, debian, innodb

I just recovered my InnoDB tables from my backup (copied ibdata1, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile0)

However, when I start mysql now, and try to access my site with InnoDB tables, *I get these errors

```
Got error -1 from storage engine
MySQL server has gone away
```

and in my /var/log/syslog I have a lot of messages like

```
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: 111019  0:21:31  InnoDB: Error: page 113644 log sequence number 12 1381339343
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12 1375387790.
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: for more information.
```

and at the end, I see

```
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: Apply batch completed
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: 111019  0:21:31  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 12 1375387790
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 4 !!!
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: 111019  0:21:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: 111019  0:21:31 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Oct 19 00:21:31 vm645 mysqld: Version: '5.1.49-3-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
```

Okay, I'd say it's ready to be connected. However, I get the same errors as stated at the start of this question. It looks like it's up but everytime I try to run query on InnoDB table it just fell down for a second.

Thoughts?

## EDIT:

Sometimes, when I'm restarting mysql it shows me in console

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)                                                            - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
......
```

and I have to start it again

## EDIT2:

For some reason, now it is throwing only

```
Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

Comment: Uhmmm. You don't restore a database by copying the ibdata files. You recover it by mysqldump and the like: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: How did you back this up?  Have you tried performing a restore to a clean install of mysql?

Comment: Try without the log files.

Comment: @Zoredache: yeah, reinstalled mysql package & backed up - classic rsync, no mysqldump

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: no, it is even worse

Comment: Now it throws only `Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'`

Comment: Now you know one of the reasons some of us are so strongly against attempting to backup MySQL at the file level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have backuped all databases (`mysqldump -p db_name > db_name.sql`), reinstalled mysql completely and imported my databases back (`mysql -p db_name < db_name.sql`). It works now.

Side note: Never, ever remove `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`.

Answer (score 0):

How did you made the backup? Copying over the mysql directory is a very bad idea, and wont work well. 
Use mysqldump, or innobackupex.

For this problem propably it will solve your problem is you move your ib_logfile[0|1] somewhere and starting the mysql server. 
After this I would start checking if my data is corrupted in the db.

Comment: That will not solve the `log sequence number is in the future!` error message.  Moving his old `ib_logfile`s *back* might work but he likely doesn't have access to those any more.  Running enough queries to increment the sequence number beyond what it's reporting also fixes that error but using `mysqldump` and restoring from scratch is a better method if you can manage it (which he seems to have done).